# Where can I find examples of element heavy web forms?

Tags: css, layout, webforms

I would like to look at some examples of some good form layouts (web-based) that have a lot of input fields. I do a lot of web application development and a lot of my forms are input element heavy so I am always looking for good ideas on how to display my forms. For example I have a few list boxes and a lot of text boxes and some drop downs on a page along with displaying history of changes to the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I always like visiting [Wufoo](http://wufoo.com/gallery/) whenever I need some form inspiration.

Comment: Second the recommendation; I was writing the same thing when you posted.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on what your focus is data entry or user experience.  For **data entry** as the primary goal, I would keep the input boxes close together and make sure they flow very well with the tab key so the user never has to take their hands off the keyboard.  Also probably should keep the space to a minimum and try to include as many boxes on the page as possible.

For **user experience,** just about the opposite is true, you need to make sure that there is enough room to identify problems with JavaScript validation, and make sure the form works just as well for the new users as the power users.  Power users == heavy data entry users.

[Wufoo](http://wufoo.com) is pretty good on user experience but it wouldn't work well for data entry users I mentioned above.  Because the user has to stop to click a button.

Answer (score 2):

Smashing Magazine has a good roundup of CSS based form inspirations / techniques / tutorials.

Check it out [here](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2006/11/11/css-based-forms-modern-solutions/).